# SkiaSharp DrawPath, how to know what path the user has clicked

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I need to have in my android app an image where the user can click on a part of the image, and than that part will color different.
I searched a lot on this, but found no use-able solution, all I could find was that `SkiaSharp` might be the best option for this.

So I installed it and am trying now to get some result, I think I need to cut my image in the parts that the user can click on, and then display these parts so it looks like one complete image again.

On that part I have made some progress, I cut the parts from my image, save them and then use an online converter to get that image parts as `svg`
After many tries and googling I managed to show 3 parts from my image.

My next problem is, how can I know which image the user clicked on ?
I added a `TabGestureRecognizer` but it works for the complete canvas.

this is the xaml

```
<skia:SKCanvasView PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <skia:SKCanvasView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="tapGestureRecognizer" />
    </skia:SKCanvasView.GestureRecognizers>
</skia:SKCanvasView>
```

and this is my c# code

```
void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
    SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear();
            
    using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
    {
        paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill;
        paint.Color = (Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black).ToSKColor();
        paint.StrokeWidth = 1;
        // region 72, the tire
        SKPath path = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData("M52 152.1c-8.8 1.5-19.4 7.1-25.9 13.7-24.4 25.1-14.7 66.8 18.3 78.2 28.1 9.6 58-8.3 62.6-37.4 4-25.5-12.2-48.7-37.8-54.2-7.5-1.5-9.3-1.6-17.2-.3zm19.7 19.8c19.8 9 23.8 34.3 7.7 49-12 11-29.9 10.2-40.8-1.9-11.1-12.3-10.7-30.2 1.1-41.1 6.5-6 11.4-7.9 20.3-7.9 5.2 0 8.8.6 11.7 1.9z");
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

        paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
        paint.Color = StringToColor("#E7FFFF");
        paint.StrokeWidth = 1;
        // region 73, the wheel
        path = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData("M55.2 172c-1.3.6-2.8.8-3.3.4-.5-.3-.9 0-.9.6s-.4.8-1 .5c-.5-.3-1-.1-1 .4 0 .6-.9 1.1-1.9 1.1-1 0-2.1.7-2.5 1.5-.3.8-1.2 1.5-1.9 1.5-.8 0-1.9 1.1-2.5 2.5-.6 1.4-1.6 2.5-2.1 2.5-1.3 0-4.3 6.8-5.3 11.8-1.1 5.9 2 19.2 4.5 19.2.5 0 .6.4.3.9-.7 1.1 7.2 8.1 9.1 8.1.7 0 1.3.4 1.3.8 0 .5.6.9 1.3 1 .6.1 3.5.6 6.2 1.2 5.5 1.2 13.5.5 13.5-1.2 0-.6.3-.9.6-.5.4.3 1.3-.1 2.1-.9s1.9-1.2 2.4-.9c.5.4.9.1.9-.6s.3-1 .6-.6c.9.8 8.5-7.4 7.8-8.5-.3-.4 0-.8.7-.8s1-.3.6-.6c-.3-.4 0-1.2.7-2 3.5-3.5 2.5-19.3-1.6-23.8-1-1-1.5-2.4-1.1-2.9.3-.6.1-.7-.5-.3-.7.4-1.2.1-1.2-.8s-.5-1.5-1.2-1.4c-.7.2-1.2-.3-1.3-1 0-.6-.4-1.3-1-1.4-.5-.1-1.8-.9-2.8-1.8-3.3-3.1-15.6-5.6-19.5-4z");
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

        paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
        paint.Color = (Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black).ToSKColor();
        paint.StrokeWidth = 1;
        // region 14, the black line around it anyway
        path = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData("M111 112.6c-20.7 2.6-23.5 3.6-32.6 11.5l-5.5 4.9h-7.3c-9.1 0-9.8.7-9.4 9.2l.3 6.3 7.5.8c29.3 3.2 50.1 25.6 50 54-.1 26-19.5 48.8-45 52.8-4.1.6-8.1 1.3-8.8 1.5-1.5.4-1.8 30.4-.2 30.4.6 0 1-5.5 1-14.4v-14.3l6.1-.7c22.7-2.6 41.7-19.7 47.5-42.6 2.2-8.7 1.5-23.2-1.6-31.5-3-8.1-10.1-18.6-15.8-23.5-9.4-8.1-24.3-13.9-35.5-14h-3.8l.3-5.8.3-5.7 6-.3c8.7-.3 9.8-.7 15.7-5.8 8.6-7.4 10.6-8.1 32.4-10.9 28.8-3.6 32.2-3.6 36.6-.3 2 1.5 4.5 4.7 5.7 7 3.6 7.5 17.2 75.7 26.7 133.5 2.6 16.1 5.2 29.3 5.6 29.3 1.3 0 1-2.6-4.6-36.2-6.4-37.6-12.7-71.1-19.5-103-4.2-19.4-5.4-23.3-8-27.2-1.8-2.5-4.5-5.3-6.1-6.1-4.1-2.1-15.8-1.8-38 1.1z");
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

        paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill;
        paint.Color = StringToColor("#6699FF");
        paint.StrokeWidth = 1;
        // region 14, the rest
        path = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData("M133.5 112.6c-1.1.2-10.5 1.3-21 2.5-21.1 2.5-22.9 3.1-32.2 10.8-6 5-6.2 5.1-12.6 5.1-9.3 0-9.7.3-9.7 6.6v5.4h5.3c20.2 0 41.1 14.8 49.3 35 3.6 8.8 4.6 27.4 1.9 36.6-5.5 19.3-20.6 33.9-40 38.9-3.2.8-7.6 1.5-9.7 1.5H61v29h32v-20.1l4.3.3 4.2.3.3 9.7.3 9.8H186l-.5-2.8c-.3-1.5-3.2-18.7-6.5-38.2-5.9-35.7-13.2-73.8-19.6-103.5-5.3-24.6-10-29.4-25.9-26.9zM144 255v11h-8v-22h8v11z");
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
    };
            
}
```

It looks like this in the emulator, I still have many parts to do but I want to know first if I can find out what image part the user clicked on.
In this example I need to know if he clicked on the blue part, or on the black part, or on the white circle inside the black part

[image]

So, how can I do this ?

Comment: In order to detect touch points on a `SKCanvas`, you need to set `EnableTouchEvents = true` (e.g. in the constructor). Then, you need to override the `OnTouch(SKTouchEventArgs)` method with the event arguments from which you can obtain the touch location. With that information and the information of your paths, you should be able to calculate if the touch point hits one of your paths. I haven't done that before with SkiaSharp, but that's how I would start.

Comment: @ewerspej I did not found any EnableTouchEvents on SKCanvas, I did found them on the SKCanvasView. Anyway, thank you for finally getting me on a path that looks promising for finding a solution to this problem

Comment: You're right, it should have been `SKCanvasView`